# java usage of equals and hasNext

Tags: java, equals

why does this code doesn't stop? Aren't "scanner.equals(null)" and "scanner.hasNext() == false" the same or at least same role??

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = 1;
        while(true) {
            if(scanner.equals(null))
                break;
            else {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println(i + " " + line);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: even if there is absolutely no input in next line??

Comment: The scanner is only equal to null if it wasn't created in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanner.equals(null)` will always return false. It checks if an object instance is null, and it's not. In comparison, `scanner.next()` checks if the scanner can find a token.

Anyway, you are using the `nextLine` method, so you should be using `hasNextLine`, not `hasNext`:

```
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(i + " " + line);
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Okay so that means if I want scanner.equals(null) to be true, there should be the null existing in next line?

Comment: No. `scanner.equals(null)` will **never** be true.